# How much space do string constants occupy in a compiled DLL?

Tags: c#, silverlight, string, compilation

I'm trying to work out what is affecting the compiled size of my Silverlight application assembly. Clearly, I want to reduce the size of my application, and the most obvious way of doing that is to get rid of some of my constant strings (e.g. error strings - there are no images in the application or other resource intensive entities). I will subsequently pull strings from the server on demand. Before I undergo this work, I want to work out what the approximate space savings would be.

How much memory does a compiled constant take up in the compiled DLL? I'm assuming it is is stored as a UNICODE UTF-16 array of characters, and so will be 2-bytes per character? Is this correct? Is there a rule of thumb (or more rigorous rule for calculating how much compression can be made on a string for the zip compression that is used to create the final .xap file?

EDIT There's clearly some confusion being caused by the way I've asked this question. I'm not talking about the 'memory footprint' as 'the amount of memory consumed by the application' but the size of the 'dll' and consequently the xap file that is created.

Comment: UTF-8 is not "2-bytes per character" - UFT-8 could be anything between 1 and 6 (inclusive) bytes per character. Do you mean UTF-16?

Comment: @MarcGravell There are some rules so that UTF-8 is at max 4 bytes. It COULD be expanded up to 6 bytes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: A Neanderthal answer would be: compile with and without some large string constant and compare the compiled sizes.

Comment: Do you really expect that strings are going to be the dominant factor in the size of your assembly?

Comment: This is a hint which I would like to point when it comes to size reduction of xbap. Resource is the first place to look into whether you are referring any image which leads to the major size contributor to xbap. xbaps can access images from the site of origin. Usually when you add an image to a project, it is taken as a resource and it adds to the xbap. Change the property on the image to be content and set the copy action to copy always. This will reduce your xbap size and provided the images are at the site of origin you should be able to access them.

Comment: This question makes little sense.  It asks about memory size (without specifying virtual memory or RAM), then actually talks about file size.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. I've clarified the question and text.

Comment: @xanatos MarcGravell is correct or incorrect depending on what precisely is meant by "UTF-8". As originally defined, UTF-8 could encode code-points from 0 to 0x7FFFFFFF. This is allowed within ISO/IEC 10646. Since Unicode only allows characters to be encoded within the range 0 to 0x10FFFF all five or six-octet encodings (and some four-octet encodings) would either be for non-characters or over-long encodings (which should be considered invalid for security reasons). In RFC 3629 you'll see the change from allowing 6-octet to 4-octet limits as a noted change from RFC 2279.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say this: a `System.Char` (a `char` in c#) in .NET is 2 bytes. It isn't able to represent all the Unicode characters. Only the characters of the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) can be represented by a single `Char`. The others are split in surrogate pairs and need 2x`Char`. 99% of the times you won't ever use characters outside of the BMP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Now... `String`s in .NET is composed of `System.Char` (with a `NUL` terminator at the end), so it's "normally" 2 bytes per character of the BMP (plus another 2 characters for the terminator).

In the Assembly, strings are saved as UTF-16. I have just checked with an hex editor. They aren't "fully" `NUL` terminated (they have a single byte at 0), but they have their length (in bytes) + 1 (for the single byte at 0) prepended as a 16 bit value.

Comment: Good answer to part of the question. I'll assume (roughly) 2-bytes per character for the uncompressed DLL. Any idea if there is a rule of thumb for the ZIP compression that creation of the XAP. Very unscientifically, it appears that zipping a text file reduces its size by about 50%.

Comment: @StephenEllis Theorically a UTF-16 Text that uses only "ASCII" characters should be very compressable. This because one of the two bytes is always 0, so the Zip can remove it easily. So a pure (nearly pure) ASCII text in UTF-16 format shold be compressable very much (50% just removing the zero + the compression of the text). The problem is that rarely you have enough text to compress. Unless you are storing the Divine Comedy in your XAP :-)

Comment: @StephenEllis To make an example, a 35 kb UTF-8 text (1 byte x character) is compressed to 15 kb. The UTF-16 version of the same file (2 byte x character), is 70 kb and is compressed to 16 kb.

Comment: Thanks. For that info. Do you know if the logic of that is explained anywhere?

Comment: @StephenEllis What? How much a text is compressable? It's Information Theory. The final size is based on how much "information" your string contains against its occupancy and the goodness of the compressor against the "ideal" compressor.

Comment: I've never looked at compression before, so that was probably a stupid question (I'm a film editor not a coder btw). I really wanted you to explain where I might look to find out how Zip (in particular) deals with 'stringy' data. I've now seen your other comment which explains it a bit. I'll have a Google for more info. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenEllis As an abstract, you can start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression, and in the Theory subchapter you'll see `The theoretical background of compression is provided by information theory (which is closely related to algorithmic information theory) for lossless compression`

Comment: Thanks for that info. Time to take the dive!

Answer (score 3):

> reduce the memory footprint  [...] the most obvious way of doing that is to get rid of some of my constant strings (e.g. error strings) with a view to pulling them from the server on demand.

The memory footprint is not dependent on your executable size. I can have an executable of a few K's that will fill up all your gigs of ram.

Do you think creating a socket, requesting a string through some protocol like HTTP, filling an array with only required strings will not hog at least as much memory as simply an array of strings that gets compiled into your executable?

If anything, you should look in conditional compilation (`#if ENGLISH // language specific variables here #endif`) and thus only include the strings you're going to need, or use one of the many options for internationalization like [cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ckwb4b.aspx).

Comment: I was not talking memory footprint qua memory used by the application when running, but the memory footprint of the DLL as stored on the file system. I have clarified the question to reflect this.

Comment: _[Memory footprint refers to the amount of main memory that a program uses or references while running.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_footprint)_. So you're talking about executable size, which is indeed a different thing. Thanks for the update. :)

Comment: Yes. My mistake. Was using the term not as a term of art, but as folk terminology.

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly, UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII, meaning for most common characters, it will be 1 byte per character.

Comment: I think the OP is looking in particular for a strong correlation to the size in an assembly. For example, with reference to the metadata format - rather than just unicode info.